# Prove $f(x) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}A_k \sin(k\pi x) = 0 \Rightarrow A_k = 0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_+ $

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve 2(c) of [this](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gustaf/M316/mid1sol.pdf) exam.

How can you constructively prove:

> [image: equation]

In $\LaTeX$:  $$f(x) = \sum^\infty_{k=1}A_k \sin(k\pi x) = 0 \Rightarrow A_k = 0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_+ $$

In my head, what if $x = 0 $, then $f(0) = 0$, and therefore $A_k$ can be anything.

Comment: Try Fourier series. Also, $\mathrm \LaTeX$.

Comment: But thats not what the expression says. It says $u(x,0) = f(x) = 0$, with the implication being this holds true _for all $x$ in the domain_.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $\{\cos(k\pi x),\,\sin((k+1)\pi x) : k\in\mathbb N\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,2)$.

Comment: @mattos Which expression are you referring to?

Comment: The expression $u(x,0) = f(x) = 0$. It holds for all $x$ in the domain. You don't just pick various values of $x$ such as $x = 0$ and then consider what the coefficients can be.

Comment: @xbh Haha thanks!

Comment: Consider $0 = \int_0^2f(x)\sin(j\pi x)$ for some $j\in\mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @amsmath That makes sense! Thank you! :)